# Java Short.ToUnsignedInt Not defined

Tags: java, android

I'm using Android Studio and I want to use the functions

```
Byte.toUnsignedInt(...);
Short.toUnsignedInt(...);
```

But they give compiler error, even though I see that these are member functions that should be in the Short and Byte class, but it doesnt work.

Anybody have idea?

```
D:\MUD\ANDROID\ArduinoUSB\app\src\main\java\com\hariharan\arduinousb\AESCrypt.java:190: error: cannot find symbol
                d_U = Short.toUnsignedInt(ind_U[i]) % 255;
                           ^
  symbol:   method toUnsignedInt(short)
  location: class Short
D:\MUD\ANDROID\ArduinoUSB\app\src\main\java\com\hariharan\arduinousb\AESCrypt.java:191: error: cannot find symbol
                e_U = Short.toUnsignedInt(ind_U[i]) % 77;
                           ^
  symbol:   method toUnsignedInt(short)
  location: class Short
D:\MUD\ANDROID\ArduinoUSB\app\src\main\java\com\hariharan\arduinousb\AESCrypt.java:192: error: cannot find symbol
                a_U = (byte)fSb2_U[(int)d_U];
                            ^
  symbol:   variable fSb2_U
  location: class AESCrypt
D:\MUD\ANDROID\ArduinoUSB\app\src\main\java\com\hariharan\arduinousb\AESCrypt.java:193: error: cannot find symbol
                b_U = (byte)rsB2_U[(int)e_U];
                            ^
  symbol:   variable rsB2_U
  location: class AESCrypt
D:\MUD\ANDROID\ArduinoUSB\app\src\main\java\com\hariharan\arduinousb\AESCrypt.java:194: error: cannot find symbol
                c_U = (byte)(Byte.toUnsignedInt(a_U) ^ Byte.toUnsignedInt(b_U) ^ Byte.toUnsignedInt(a_U) - Byte.toUnsignedInt(b_U));
                                 ^
  symbol:   method toUnsignedInt(byte)
  location: class Byte
D:\MUD\ANDROID\ArduinoUSB\app\src\main\java\com\hariharan\arduinousb\AESCrypt.java:194: error: cannot find symbol
                c_U = (byte)(Byte.toUnsignedInt(a_U) ^ Byte.toUnsignedInt(b_U) ^ Byte.toUnsignedInt(a_U) - Byte.toUnsignedInt(b_U));
                                                           ^
  symbol:   method toUnsignedInt(byte)
  location: class Byte
D:\MUD\ANDROID\ArduinoUSB\app\src\main\java\com\hariharan\arduinousb\AESCrypt.java:194: error: cannot find symbol
                c_U = (byte)(Byte.toUnsignedInt(a_U) ^ Byte.toUnsignedInt(b_U) ^ Byte.toUnsignedInt(a_U) - Byte.toUnsignedInt(b_U));
                                                                                     ^
  symbol:   method toUnsignedInt(byte)
  location: class Byte
D:\MUD\ANDROID\ArduinoUSB\app\src\main\java\com\hariharan\arduinousb\AESCrypt.java:194: error: cannot find symbol
                c_U = (byte)(Byte.toUnsignedInt(a_U) ^ Byte.toUnsignedInt(b_U) ^ Byte.toUnsignedInt(a_U) - Byte.toUnsignedInt(b_U));
                                                                                                               ^
  symbol:   method toUnsignedInt(byte)
  location: class Byte
D:\MUD\ANDROID\ArduinoUSB\app\src\main\java\com\hariharan\arduinousb\AESCrypt.java:195: error: cannot find symbol
                low_U = (byte)(0x0F & Byte.toUnsignedInt(c_U));
                                          ^
  symbol:   method toUnsignedInt(byte)
  location: class Byte
D:\MUD\ANDROID\ArduinoUSB\app\src\main\java\com\hariharan\arduinousb\AESCrypt.java:196: error: cannot find symbol
                high_U = (byte)((0xF0 & Byte.toUnsignedInt(b_U)) >> 4);
                                            ^
  symbol:   method toUnsignedInt(byte)
  location: class Byte
D:\MUD\ANDROID\ArduinoUSB\app\src\main\java\com\hariharan\arduinousb\AESCrypt.java:199: error: cannot find symbol
                d_U = Short.toUnsignedInt(ind_U[k]) % 255;
                           ^
  symbol:   method toUnsignedInt(short)
  location: class Short
D:\MUD\ANDROID\ArduinoUSB\app\src\main\java\com\hariharan\arduinousb\AESCrypt.java:200: error: cannot find symbol
                e_U = Short.toUnsignedInt(ind_U[k]) % 89;
                           ^
  symbol:   method toUnsignedInt(short)
  location: class Short
D:\MUD\ANDROID\ArduinoUSB\app\src\main\java\com\hariharan\arduinousb\AESCrypt.java:201: error: cannot find symbol
                a_U = (byte)rsB2_U[(int)e_U];
                            ^
  symbol:   variable rsB2_U
  location: class AESCrypt
D:\MUD\ANDROID\ArduinoUSB\app\src\main\java\com\hariharan\arduinousb\AESCrypt.java:202: error: cannot find symbol
                b_U = (byte)rsB2_U[(int)d_U];
                            ^
  symbol:   variable rsB2_U
  location: class AESCrypt
D:\MUD\ANDROID\ArduinoUSB\app\src\main\java\com\hariharan\arduinousb\AESCrypt.java:203: error: cannot find symbol
                c_U = (byte)(Byte.toUnsignedInt(a_U) ^ Byte.toUnsignedInt(b_U) ^ Byte.toUnsignedInt(c_U));
                                 ^
  symbol:   method toUnsignedInt(byte)
  location: class Byte
D:\MUD\ANDROID\ArduinoUSB\app\src\main\java\com\hariharan\arduinousb\AESCrypt.java:203: error: cannot find symbol
                c_U = (byte)(Byte.toUnsignedInt(a_U) ^ Byte.toUnsignedInt(b_U) ^ Byte.toUnsignedInt(c_U));
                                                           ^
  symbol:   method toUnsignedInt(byte)
  location: class Byte
D:\MUD\ANDROID\ArduinoUSB\app\src\main\java\com\hariharan\arduinousb\AESCrypt.java:203: error: cannot find symbol
                c_U = (byte)(Byte.toUnsignedInt(a_U) ^ Byte.toUnsignedInt(b_U) ^ Byte.toUnsignedInt(c_U));
                                                                                     ^
  symbol:   method toUnsignedInt(byte)
  location: class Byte
D:\MUD\ANDROID\ArduinoUSB\app\src\main\java\com\hariharan\arduinousb\AESCrypt.java:204: error: cannot find symbol
                high_U = (byte)(0x0F & Byte.toUnsignedInt(c_U));
                                           ^
  symbol:   method toUnsignedInt(byte)
  location: class Byte
D:\MUD\ANDROID\ArduinoUSB\app\src\main\java\com\hariharan\arduinousb\AESCrypt.java:205: error: cannot find symbol
                low_U = (byte)((0xF0 & Byte.toUnsignedInt(c_U)) >> 4);
                                           ^
  symbol:   method toUnsignedInt(byte)
  location: class Byte
19 errors

 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Answer (score 0):

See javadoc of [`Short.toUnsignedInt(short x)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Short.html#toUnsignedInt-short-):

> Since: 1.8

The method was added in Java 8, so compiling on older versions of Java will fail.

If you look at the Java 7 doc for [`Short`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Short.html), you'll see that the method doesn't exist.

Comment: I have Java 8, but it still doesnt work. Still, what a strange world we live in, where nobody in the world from java 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 needed to convert a short to an unsigned int until now java 8. The high and mighty Java "Gods" who designed the language must exist outside this universe where they have no need of unsigned data, only us mortals and riff raff have need of such petty things. We should be grateful they remembered to put addition and subtraction in there before we got to java 10.

Comment: Strange java can do all these fantastic things, but having an unsigned byte it too much for them.

Comment: It's not like unsigned widening of short to int is difficult to do: `myInt = myShort & 0xFFFF;`. `Short.toUnsignedInt()` is just a nice convenience method.

Comment: Note that having Java 8 installed does not necessarily mean you are using it in *that* project.